# How can I change a string to be all lowecase and push something to the end?

Tags: javascript

So I have a function that will be called with a 1 word string.
Test("ABCD")

my code:

```
function Test(x)

    var str=""
    str.push($)
    x.toLowerCase()
    return str
```

//So I want the output to change the "ABCD" into "abcd$"

Comment: *"The toLowerCase() method returns the value of the string converted to lower case. toLowerCase() does not affect the value of the string str itself."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: I recommend working through some basic JavaScript tutorials or a good beginner's book. `push` is an array method, not a string method. `toLowerCase` *returns* a new string in lower case, it doesn't modify the string you call it on (strings are immutable). String literals (such as the `$` you want to add) must be in quotes. ...

Comment: There is NO push method on a string? You do nothing to combine x with the string you are building.

Answer (score 1):

You are accepting the argument `x` in the function and running `toLowerCase` on it. The output is not having any value from the input.

Also there is no push method defined for string. It can be [String.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat). Even that is not needed, you could make use of arithematic `+` itsel for concatenation or string leterals.

Just lowercase the input append a `$` symbol. Its done!!

Im making use of `.toString()` method aswell. To ensure code is not breaking for other input types

It should be

```js
function Test(x) {
  return x.toString().toLowerCase() + '$'
}
console.log(Test("ABCD"));
```

Or Simply.

```js
Test = (x) => `${ x.toString().toLowerCase() }$`;
console.log(Test("ABCD"));
```

Comment: You could add `if (typeof x === 'string' || x instanceof String)` to ensure that x is a string.

Comment: Yeah. Or `x.toString()` for a safer side

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example, please change the text which you want to add at end as you wish.

I passed the string in function through console.log but you can call the function as you wish without console.log.

```js
function capFirst(str) {
     return str.toLowerCase().concat('', '$');
 }

console.log(capFirst('ABCD'));
```